# Spark ALS recommendation score

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm wondering if I can get somehow the sense if predicted values are good or bad. I get a score for each item but is there a way to find maximum available score? Let's say I want to recommended only those best and prediction returned 20 items. How to choose the good ones?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution is to simply sort the items by their predicted ratings (scores). There is no a priori bound on these values.